# Last empty row in excel file

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to write a function that enters trader data into an excel file, I would like each trader to have their own sheet. During testing, I checked if two positions would write themselves into one sheet but unfortunately they overwrite each other and not write themselves into the next free row as I assumed. Code below

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('traders.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
     writer.book=self.wb
     writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in self.wb.worksheets)
     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{trader}', startrow=-1)
     writer.save()
```

I wonder what argument to give so that the data is not overwritten but goes to the next free row. Thank you in advance for any advice :) Kacper

Comment: what is `self.wb`? You are assigning the `book` attribute of your writer to a different variable so I'm not sure what the expected behavior is and what you can then pass the writer to `df.to_excel()`

Comment: @myz540   self.wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

Comment: I'm not sure you need that. Using the context manager to create the `ExcelWriter` handle should work. Can you try removing the `writer.book = self.wb` line?